# apple mach-O Linker Error when opening older app

Tags: xcode8

I am getting an error when trying to run app from x-code

ld: library not found for -lxml2.2.7.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

the app I am trying to open was build in 2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRJL1.png)